# How to wire a 230VAC motor with 4 wires. Model is: YDK139-300-4 300w

Tags: motor, induction-motor

I am newbie in electricity but got to wire a 230VAC motor with 4 wires. Model is: YDK139-300-4 300w. Could you check the diagram in the picture and advise please?

[image: motor]

Comment: Can you translate the markings into English and do you have a data sheet for the motor?

Comment: The wiring diagram is literally right there on the motor. I would not recommend connecting something to the mains if you're a newbie in electricity (sic).

Comment: Hi Andy, I got only this picture. In the diagram, left hand side scripts are for wire colors. yellow, red, blue and black. on right hand side with a capacitor, two white. I got it translated by another person.

Comment: Try to connect L and N, isolate the other two wires.

Comment: Thanks Marko. As I've seen other diagrams with English, the 2 coils were named as Start and Run. Also, seen 2 wires to L and other 2 wires to N. And by switching one from each, it changes rotation direction. Apparently because of capacitor. Would it be okay for running for a long time with only 2 wires connected? Thanks. Jerry.

Comment: Hi @MrGerber. I would appreciate if you could only tell me which 2 wires are permanently on L and N, and which two wires are selectively connected in order to change rotor direction, I can wire it to the necessary direction. Thanks, Jerry.

Answer (score 1):

I would connect N to the top wire with the symbol in the circle. I believe that symbol is an over-temperature protection device. Connect L to H, M, or L for high, medium or low speed. N and L can probably be interchanged with no bad effect.

The direction of rotation is indicated by the arrow on the left with "ROT" above it. The motor can not be reversed because the connections necessary to do that are apparently permanently connected inside the motor. The motor likely does not produce very much starting torque. It is likely designed to drive a fan.

The winding connected to the capacitor is the auxiliary or start winding. Since the capacitor is permanently connected, the motor is called a permanent split capacitor (PSC) motor. Also since the capacitor is not disconnected after starting, the start winding is called an auxiliary winding.

The coil with the H, M, and L connections seems to be the auxiliary winding. Changing the connections changes the voltage applied to the main and auxiliary windings simultaneously. That is a somewhat unusual configuration. With that design, it appears that the motor could not be reversed even if all of the connection points were available for changing connections.

Comment: Very informative. Will follow instructions.

Answer (score 0):

YSK139-300-4 is a PSC Motor from [Gems, Global electric motor solutions](http://gemsmotor.com/ac-fan-blower-psc-motor). They suggest the following wiring:

[image]

And as noted [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_motor#Permanent-split_capacitor_motor):

> rotation is changed by reversing the connection between the main winding and the start circuit.

EDIT: 
As stated also on the GEMC webpage:

> ADVANTAGES OF A PSC MOTOR:
>   
> [...]
> Their rotatory motion can be easily reversed without any changes in their torque characteristics.

Comment: Very informative. Will follow instructions.

Comment: These diagrams conflict with the diagram on the label. I would use the connections shown on the label.

Comment: Yeah, well - that's what you get for buying Chinese without data sheets, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your profile does not indicate where in the world you are. It makes a difference, because if you are in North America, you would NOT connect the Neutral (N) to this at all. Hot to Neutral here is 120V, to get 240V you need two Hot lines, L1 and L2. Pretty much everywhere else in the world, 240V (nominal) is Hot and Neutral.

Also if you are in North America, that motor will spin 20% (6/5) faster because of the difference in frequency. If connected to a centrifugal load like a pump or fan, that will result in the load on the motor increasing to 172% of the design, likely overloading your motor. keep that in mind. but again if you are NOT in North America, then ignore all of that...